# PHP form to returning all the information

Tags: php, forms

I am a complete novice when it comes to php, I have got the below php which sends me back the 'message' and sends an auto response to the user, as well as redirecting them to the 'thank you' page. Problem I am having is that it won't return the users name that they fill in on the form, any ideas?

```
<?php

$youremail = "ally.baird81@gmail.com"; //this is where the email will be sent to

@extract($_POST);$name = filter_var($name, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$message  = filter_var($message, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    if (mail($youremail, 'Message from website.', $message, "From: Krew Kut Hair<$email>")) {

        $autoreply = "Thank you for enquiring at Krew Kut Hair, we will be in contact shortly";
        $subject   = "Thank you for your enquiry!";
        mail($email, $subject, $autoreply, "From: Krew Kut Hair<$email>");

    }
} else {
    echo "Please enter a valid email address";
}

header("Location: thanks.html");
```

Comment: Put `$name` somewhere in the email, what's the problem?

Comment: BTW, using `extract` is a very bad idea. What if they send a parameter called `youremail`? It will replace your assignment of the variable.

Comment: Using extract() on superglobals is basically just trying to reproduce `register_globals`. That abomination was rightly terminated and tortured to death. Do **NOT** try to recreate it.

Comment: Hi Barmar, thanks for your reply but the problem is not getting the name in the reply message to the user but actually receiving the name from the html form input. I receive the $message from the html form but not the $name. Any ideas for a php newbie?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an input named "name" like:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="" />
```

Check if it's containing data with e.g. :

```
echo 'The value of name is ['.$name.']';
```

If it is containing data you just can use the `$name` variable in your message. If it isn't there is probably something wrong in your HTML form.

```
<?php

$youremail = "ally.baird81@gmail.com"; //this is where the email will be sent to

@extract($_POST);$name = filter_var($name, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$message    = filter_var($message, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$content    = "<strong>Name:<strong><br />".$name."<br />";
$content   .= "<strong>Message:<strong><br />".$message."<br />";

if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    if (mail($youremail, 'Message from website.<br />', $content, "From: Krew Kut Hair<$email>")) {

        $autoreply = "Hi ".$name.". Thank you for enquiring at Krew Kut Hair, we will be in contact shortly";
        $subject   = "Thank you for your enquiry!";
        mail($email, $subject, $autoreply, "From: Krew Kut Hair<$email>");

    }
} else {
    echo "Please enter a valid email address";
}

header("Location: thanks.html");
```

Also read the comments on your question. I strongly recommend to find an other way instead of using `extract()`.

Comment: Thanks, I am a complete php novice and hacking bits and pieces together to get this to work (probably not the best idea I know), will look into extract() issue. The problem is not getting the name in the reply message but actually receiving the name from the html form input

Comment: Pretty sure it is to do with the PHP and not the HTML as if I add $name to the message as has been recommended it will provide the name in the auto response message. But again I can't get it to receive the name in the forms return values.

Comment: What do you mean? If the variable `name` contains the form value of the 'name'-input you already have the value of the returned form right? If you want to get the name of the POST data the form submitted you should use `$_POST['name']`.

Comment: I will try $_POST['name'], sorry to sound like a PHP dunce but I am taking it I should include this before the IF statement?

Comment: What is your goal? What do you want to the with the `name` field?

Comment: So when the user fills out the name field on the form, the site owner will receive that value.

Comment: No not even receiving an email on submission for the user or the site owner?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the name is in one of the form fields, you should be able to retrieve it.  As Barmar says - all you have to do is use it somewhere in the body or the message. How can you tell the name is missing if you don't echo it out somewhere.
Try this:

```
$autoreply = "Thank you ".$name."  for ...
```

If the name is still "missing" - you can try to see all the post variables like this:

```
echo "<PRE>Post Vars\n"; print_r($_POST);
```